# Provide variable argument list

Tags: matlab, arguments, matlab-struct

I have a function which accepts a variable number of input variables. The problem is, the number of input arguments I'm going to provide varies. As such, I store all the arguments in a structure:

```
function grandAvg(datafiles)

% Load up all averaged datafiles
avgs = struct();
for n=1:length(datafiles)
    avgs(n).avg = load(datafiles{n});
end
```

My question is, **is there a way to expand this argument for the function?** I need a way to convert this:

```
% DOES NOT WORK
avg = ft_timelockgrandaverage(cfg, avgs);
```

to this:

```
% WOULD WORK, BUT DO NOT WANT TO TYPE IT OUT
avg = ft_timelockgrandaverage(cfg, avgs(1).avg, ..., avgs(n).avg);
```

---

*EDIT TO ADD:* So apparently my question wasn't clear. I know how to construct the function using `varargin`. My question was, if I am trying to use a build-in function which I don't want to or can't modify, how can I *provide* arguments in a variable manner? I.e., I don't know ahead of time how many argument's I'll be providing, so when I call the function, I'll have to call it with X number of arguments. In effect, I'm looking for a way to turn this:

```
someVar  <1xN struct>
```

into this:

```
someVar1  <1x1 struct>
someVar2  <1x1 struct>
...
someVarN  <1x1 struct>
```

in a programmatic manner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after playing around, I've got it. Using the example from above:

Given an `1xN struct` named `foo`, where each `foo(n)` contains the field `bar`, I would call the function as:

```
function(foo(:).bar);
```

This is the same as typing

```
function(foo(1).bar, foo(2).bar, ..., foo(N).bar);
```

In this way, I can dynamically expand or shrink `foo` and still have no problem calling the function.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) to store your data would be to use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html). For example:

```
nFiles = numel(datafiles);  %# Number of files
avgs = cell(1,nFiles);      %# Initialize an empty cell array
for iFile = 1:nFiles        %# Loop over the files
  avgs{iFile} = load(datafiles{iFile});  %# Load the data into each cell
end
avg = ft_timelockgrandaverage(cfg, avgs{:});  %# Pass the contents to a function
```

The syntax `avgs{:}` dumps the contents of the cell array into what's called a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html). It is equivalent to typing `avgs{1}, avgs{2}, ... , avgs{end}`. The syntax `foo(:).bar` from [the answer you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836846/provide-variable-argument-list/6845122#6845122) also creates a comma-separated list, but I find that using cell arrays for such a purpose is generally cleaner than using a structure array.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can use variable length  input argument list 
varargin

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/varargin.html

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do such a thing, by means of the `varargin` construct in MATLAB. This will be something like:

```
avg = ft_timelockgrandaverage(cfg, avgs.avg);
```

And for the function `ft_timelockgrandaverage`

```
function output = ft_timelockgrandaverage(config, varargin)
% your code here
```

`varargin` will be a cell array: `{avgs(1).avg, avgs(2).avg, ..., avgs(3).avg}` which you can process.